# Saving Nested Django Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 3 models. `Question`, `Choice`, and `Cover`. Question can have many choices and each choice can have only 1 cover. I implemented the `Question` and `Choice` as serializers and it worked successfully, now i'm trying to add on the `Cover`. Here's what I have:

```
class CreateQuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choice_set = ChoiceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('user', 'status', 'choice_set')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        choices_validated_data = validated_data.pop('choice_set')
        question = Question.objects.create(**validated_data)
        choices_serializer = self.fields['choice_set']

        for choice in choices_validated_data:
            choice['question'] = question
        choices_serializer.create(choices_validated_data)
        return question

class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choice_cover = ChoiceCoverSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ('choice', 'choice_cover')


class ChoiceCoverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ChoiceCover
        fields = ('cover',)
```

When I try to save data like so:

```
{
    "user": 179,
    "question": "Who will win the election?",
    "choice_set": [
      {
        "choice": "Lorem",
        "choice_cover": "C4FF33"
      },
      {
        "choice": "Ipsum",
        "choice_cover": "FF5733"
      }
     ]
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "choice_set": [
        {
            "choice_cover": {
                "non_field_errors": [
                    "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str."
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "choice_cover": {
                "non_field_errors": [
                    "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str."
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to override the **`create()`** method of **`ChoiceSerializer`** class

Comment: @ArakkalAbu How would I do that when choices are being created in the `CreateQuestionSerializer`

Comment: That doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu hmm, how would you reference which cover is which choice?

Comment: order of class definition should be ```ChoiceCoverSerializer```, ```ChoiceSerializer```. as you are using ```ChoiceCoverSerializer``` in ```ChoiceSerializer```.

Comment: you are adding ```choice_cover = ChoiceCoverSerializer(many=False)``` in  ```ChoiceSerializer```, so ```choice_cover``` field in JSON will be like ```"choice_cover": {"cover":"FF5733"}```.

Comment: instead of dict for ```choice_cover``` you are giving a string, so error occurred.

Comment: @AkashPagar how would i make it so that it doesn't need a dict?

Comment: instead of using ```choice_cover = ChoiceCoverSerializer(many=False)``` in ```ChoiceSerializer``` you can use ```choice_cover = StringField(required=True)``` in ```ChoiceSerializer```. try using this